# Data Table : Table has no columns

Tags: json, datatable, google-visualization

I am getting **Table has no columns.×** issue and i am not able to figure out why... Can you please help me understand whats wrong?

**My HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "<JSON URL>",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JAVA CODE:**

I am using code similar to one presented in the example

https://github.com/google/google-visualization-java/blob/master/examples/src/java/SimpleExampleServlet.java

**MY JSON :**

```
{
  "rows":[
    {
      "cells":[
        {
          "value":{"value":"A","objectToFormat":"A","null":false,"type":"TEXT"},
          "formattedValue":null,
          "customProperties":{},
          "null":false,
          "type":"TEXT"
        },
        {
          "value":{"value":"1","objectToFormat":"1","null":false,"type":"TEXT"},
          "formattedValue":null,
          "customProperties":{},
          "null":false,
          "type":"TEXT"
        }
      ],
      "customProperties":{}
    },
    {
      "cells":[
        {
          "value":{"value":"B","objectToFormat":"B","null":false,"type":"TEXT"},
          "formattedValue":null,
          "customProperties":{},
          "null":false,
          "type":"TEXT"
        },
        {
          "value":{"value":"0","objectToFormat":"0","null":false,"type":"TEXT"},
          "formattedValue":null,
          "customProperties":{},
          "null":false,
          "type":"TEXT"
        }
      ],
      "customProperties":{}
    }
  ],
  "customProperties":{},
  "warnings":[],
  "localeForUserMessages":null,
  "numberOfRows":2,
  "numberOfColumns":2,
  "columnDescriptions":[
    {"id":"Option","type":"TEXT","label":"Option","pattern":"","customProperties":{}},
    {"id":"Count","type":"TEXT","label":"Count","pattern":"","customProperties":{}}
  ]
}
```

Comment: How do you expect google visualization should be able to render this JSON? It is impossible - you must sanitize it into a more table-like value-oriented format. If you revisit the example you have copied the code from -> **https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example** the example JSON is completely different ...

Comment: I am using DataTable Google API to generate that JSON... it is available at https://github.com/google/google-visualization-java/blob/master/examples/src/java/SimpleExampleServlet.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As were noted, `google.visualization.DataTable` expects JSON data to be provided in the format that is different from the one specified in question. Basically there are two options available:

- modify Java servlet to generate JSON in format supported by `google.visualization.DataTable`
- convert the generated JSON data

Below is demonstrated how to convert the provided JSON data to be compatible with `google.visualization.DataTable`(second option)

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    /*var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "<JSON URL>",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;*/

    var jsonData = {
        "rows": [
            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "value": { "value": "A", "objectToFormat": "A", "null": false, "type": "TEXT" },
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": { "value": "1", "objectToFormat": "1", "null": false, "type": "TEXT" },
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT"
                    }
                ],
                "customProperties": {}
            },
            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "value": { "value": "B", "objectToFormat": "B", "null": false, "type": "TEXT" },
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": { "value": "0", "objectToFormat": "0", "null": false, "type": "TEXT" },
                        "formattedValue": null,
                        "customProperties": {},
                        "null": false,
                        "type": "TEXT"
                    }
                ],
                "customProperties": {}
            }
        ],
        "customProperties": {},
        "warnings": [],
        "localeForUserMessages": null,
        "numberOfRows": 2,
        "numberOfColumns": 2,
        "columnDescriptions": [
            { "id": "Option", "type": "TEXT", "label": "Option", "pattern": "", "customProperties": {} },
            { "id": "Count", "type": "TEXT", "label": "Count", "pattern": "", "customProperties": {} }
        ]
    };



    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(convertToDataTableJson(jsonData));
    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, { width: 400, height: 240 });
}



function convertToDataTableJson(json)
{
     var outJson = { cols: [], rows: []};  
     json.columnDescriptions.forEach(function(c){
         outJson.cols.push({ "id": c.id, "label": c.label, "pattern": c.pattern, "type": c.type == "TEXT" ? "string" : "number" }); 
     });

     json.rows.forEach(function(r){
         var cells = {c : []};
         r.cells.forEach(function(c){
             cells.c.push({ "v": c.value.value, "f": null });
         });   
         outJson.rows.push(cells);
     });
     return outJson;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```